# Linux to Windows copying network script

Tags: linux, bash, backup, rsync

I need to improve my method, or even change it completely, for copying files on a private network from multiple Windows machines to a central Linux machine. How this works is that I run the script below as a cron job every 5 minutes to copy data from say 10 Windows machines, all with a shared folder, to the central Linux machine that gets collected each day. So in theory the Linux machine at the end of the day should have all the data that has changed on the Windows machines.

```
#!/bin/sh
USER='/home/user/Documents/user.ip'
IPADDY=$USER
USERNAME=$USER
while read IPADDY USERNAME; do
mkdir /mnt/$USERNAME
mkdir /home/user/Documents/$USERNAME
smbmount //$IPADDY/$USERNAME /mnt/$USERNAME -o   username=usera,password=password,rw,uid=user
rsync -zrv --progress --include='*.pdf' --include='*.txt' --include='issues' --exclude='*' /mnt/$USERNAME/ /home/user/Documents/$USERNAME/
done < $USER
```

The script works fine but it doesn't seem to be the best method as a lot of the time data is not being copied across or not all the data is copied correctly.

Do you think that this is the best approach or can someone point me in a better solution?

Comment: How is the data not copied correctly? For pulling the data `rsync` is a good choice. I assume you don't want to install additional software on the other clients?

Comment: It may help to edit your question above with these elements of infomation. 1. What is type of 'data' you are pulling. 2. Are the processes that create it running constantly? 3. If so, then is the reason your combined data is bad is a syncronization issue? 4. If so continued, Can you get the indivual processes to stop running at a certain time each day so you know your data 'system' is quiet? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

How about git repository? Wouldn't it be easier? You could easily also track the changes.

Comment: Would GIT work in the way that it would help me gather the files from the different laptops and make sure that the all the data is copied!?

Comment: @Grimlockz: Yes. You can use git this way. From git perspective you can have one master branch and many other branches created from the master. Then you need to merge changes from each branch to the master branch.